# vue js использование key

Tags: vue.js

```
   <select>
            <option v-for="options in setData" v-bind:key="options.id" >{{options.name}}</option>
        </select>
```

как я могу получить выбранный значение ключа и использовать его дальше для передачи в method или функции 
я сделал v-bind:value в цикле теперь я хочу при выборе из селекта получить что я забиндил v-bind:value а v-model дает название мне надо создат список значение плюс ключ при выборе значеия я хочу получить ключ и передать его

Comment: `key` используется для внутренних нужд vue. Определи свой prop и передай id туда

Comment: мне надо при выборе значения в селекте получить его ключ как это лутче сделать

Comment: для `<option>` лучший вариант - это атрибут `value`, конечно

Comment: а как его вытянуть тогда чтоб передать в функцию

Comment: смотря как пытаешься) Офф. сайт читал? https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

Comment: читал но там кроме v-model ничего нету

Comment: а чем v-model не устраивает?

Comment: Опиши в вопросе конкретно что нужно, включая момент, с которым не получается. Иначе не понятно в чем проблема

Comment: я сделал v-bind:value в цикле теперь я хочу при выборе из селекта получить что я забиндил v-bind:value а v-model дает название мне надо создат список значение плюс ключ при выборе значеия я хочу получить ключ и передать его

Comment: если `<option :value="options.id">...` то в v-model будет этот id. Если нет - значит что-то не так указано

Answer (score 0):

```
<option v-for="options in setData" v-bind:key="options.id" >{{options.name}}</option>
```

Такая запись не совсем корректна, потому что сейчас `:key` опирается на значения данных `options.id`
А оно может быть не уникальным, это создаст дополнительные проблемы при рендеринге списка
Рекомендуется создать отдельную переменную-счетчик

```
<option v-for="(options, i) in setData" 
        :key="i"
>
  {{options.name}}
</option>
```

Если вам нужно передать в функцию порядок элемента, то это легко сделать передав параметр вызываемому методу

```
@change="selectElement(i)"
```